# Remove complete html tag with content

Tags: swift, regex, string

I have this content:

```
var a = "Hello <sup foot_note=\"81277\">1</sup> World"
```

And I want to remove the whole html tag: `<sup foot_note=\"81277\">1</sup>`

I tried it with this code:

```
let str1 = getText().replacingOccurrences(of: "<[^>]+>", with: "", options: .regularExpression, range: nil)
var str2 = str1.replacingOccurrences(of: "&[^;]+;", with: "", options: .regularExpression, range: nil)
```

This does not remove the "1", so I get "Hello 1 World". How can I solve this?

Comment: Thanks this works!

Answer (score 1):

For the current example, you can use

```
a.replacingOccurrences(of: #"(?s)\s*<(\w+)(?:\s[^>]+)?>.*?</\1>"#, with: "", options: .regularExpression, range: nil) # #1
a.replacingOccurrences(of: #"(?i)\s*<sup(?:\s[^>]+)?>[^<]*</sup>"#, with: "", options: .regularExpression, range: nil) # #2
```

Note that regexps are bad at removing arbitrary HTML tags (Line #1 above), as they can be nested. The first solution might actually be rather dangerous

Thus, if you just want to remove `sup` tags with their contents (that usually do not contain nested tags and are not nested themselves), you can use Line #2 regex.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/K2ynyV/1).

**Details**

- `(?i)` - Case insensitive search
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `<sup` - `<sup` string
- `(?:\s[^>]+)?` - an optional occurrence of a whitespace and then one or more chars other than `>`
- `>`  - a `>` char
- `[^<]*` - zero or more chars other than `<`
- `</sup>` - a `</sup>` text.